# React Native editable FlatList How to edit item data

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

React Native editable FlatList – How to edit item data in a List?

Hi code community, I am new in reactive native and I need some help. I am trying to handle a data update in FlatList. where the user can change the text name for whatever they want. Exemplo if the user creates a folder named "Bar" but later on decides to change the name for "Bar1". How can I do it??? Here is my code so far...

My Modal State

```
const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
```

My FlatList Component... discard data={folderToDisplay}

```
<FlatList numColumns={4} data={folderToDisplay} renderItem={renderItem} />
```

My renderItem={renderItem} is set like this: where {itemData.item.value} is here I am fetching my text name. We can replace {itemData.item.value} to Bar if you wish.

```
    const renderItem = (itemData) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.folderNameContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            setModalVisible(true);
          }}
        >
          <Text style={styles.itemText}>{itemData.item.value}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

When I press the text name a Modal opens.

```
<Modal animationType="fade" transparent={true} visible={modalVisible}>
        <SimpleModal
          closeModal={onCloseModal}
        />
      </Modal>
```

...And when I press cancel it close.

```
const onCloseModal = () => {
    setModalVisible(false);
  };
```

My SimpleModal component is set like this: I could make my code all in one place but it looks ugly.

```
const SimpleModal = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.centeredView}>
      <View style={styles.modalView}>
        <Text style={styles.modalText}>Change Name!</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInput}
          placeholder="Type Here..."
          maxLength={15}
        />
        <View style={styles.saveAndCancelContainer}>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Button title="Save" color="#87CEEB" onPress={props.renameFolder} />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Button title="Cancel" color="red" onPress={props.closeModal} />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Now the goal here is in my TextInput the user type a new name and then press Save. When onPress it will update the name for the new name. and close the modal. So far this is what I have:

```
<Modal animationType="fade" transparent={true} visible={modalVisible}>
        <SimpleModal
          renameFolder={handleRenameFolder}
        />
      </Modal>

const handleRenameFolder = () => {
    ///....????
    setModalVisible(false);
  };
```

Comment: Do you want to change data of an object of a state array? is that your question?

Comment: Yes, @RyanSaleh.

Comment: Thank you for asking